# httpdocs and httpsdocs folders

Tags: hosting

In the default directory of my hosting server I can see 2 folders among others:

```
httpdocs
```

and

```
httpsdocs
```

Is this a common directory structure ? If I add stuff to httpsdocs it is automatically protected by SSL ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some PHP control panel utilities use this directory structure, [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) is the one that I have seen use this. The framework automatically routes all **https://** requests to files located in the httpsdocs directory and all **http://** requests to the httpdocs directory.

So with one of these frameworks you can be assured that any pages loaded from httpsdocs will have come through an **https://** request and will be SSL encrypted.

Comment: what if I have an unique CMS including my website and web shop and, of course, I don't want to split it. What should I do ?

Comment: I would recommend contacting your hosting company since you said your being hosted on their servers they would probably have a solution for you. Sorry I don't have a better answer, but I'm sure they have dealt with situations similar to yours before.

Comment: ok thanks. However if I just include all my website in the secure folder and I use https protocol for entire website, is it fine ? Right ?

Comment: yea, it's not the "ideal" solution obviously, but it would work. You just have to make sure all your links are setup to route to https properly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's a common structure.

httpdocs is the folder used by web server when you type http://yourdomain.com in the browser. Content is not encrypted.

httpsdocs is the folder used by web server when you type https://yourdomain.com in the browser. (SSL). Everything you put there will be encrypted using SSL. Check with your hosting company that you have a valid certificate.

If you want your content in the httpdocs folder to be the same for your https URL, you can ask your hosting company to configure that for you.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely require an SSL certificate so that your web traffic is encrypted. If you place files in the httpsdocs folder and you don't have an SSL certificate there will be errors in some browsers.  You can force SSL in .htaccess.